# R string match between tags

Tags: regex, r

In R how to get all file names in a directory for which start and end name is known?

```
list.files(dir_path, pattern = "^my_")
```

gives all file which starts with "my_"

```
list.files(dir_path, pattern = ".R$")
```

gives all file which ends with ".R"

But how do I apply both the patters ?

```
list.files(dir_path, pattern = "^my_*.R")
```

gives character(0)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression:

```
^my_.*\\.R
```

BTW, `.` matches any character. So `.R$` will match `AIR`, not only files that ends with `.R`. If you want to match the `.` literally you need to escape it.

```
list.files(dir_path, pattern = "^my_.*\\.R$")
```